# Retry Option Example in Cadence for java client

Tags: java, cadence-workflow

I am looking for retry option example for cadence in java, for example I am trying below code snippet but it seems the activity is not re-tried

```
@ActivityMethod(scheduleToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 30)
@MethodRetry(maximumAttempts = 2, initialIntervalSeconds = 1, expirationSeconds = 30, maximumIntervalSeconds = 30)
String getGreetingContentOverTheWeb(URL url) throws IOException;
```

for the above activity I am expecting that if it fails should be re-tried automatically, below is how I am calling it

```
@Override
public String getGreeting(String name) {
    // This is a blocking call that returns only after the activity has completed.
    try {
        String content = activities.getGreetingContentOverTheWeb(new URL("http://localhost:3000/import-map/books"));
        return activities.composeGreeting(content, name);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return activities.composeGreeting("Hello", name);
    
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything incorrect here,

Below is the snapshot from the frontend

[image]

Comment: What is the value of the attempt field of the ActivityTaskScheduled event in the workflow execution history?

Comment: Hi @MaximFateev, added the screenshot from the workflow execution for your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the event history, it looks like the activity is retried. I determined it by looking at the `ActivityTaskStarted.attempt` field. The number there is equal to the number of retries. So activity executed exactly two times as requested per the specified retry policy.

I know that the name is super confusing as attempts should start from 1 and not from 0. We already [fixed this](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/pull/554) in the [temporal.io](https://www.temporal.io/) Cadence fork my team maintains.

Comment: Thank You @Maxim Fateev, I re-verified and the re-try option is working as expected, The re-try count starting from zero was confusing but now its clear.

Comment: Also, few days after I started learning Cadence I realized that there is temporal.io (fork of cadence) with some new features which is also mentioned by you in the above comment, do you recommend Cadence or Temporal going forward for new projects ?.

Comment: Yes, I recommend using Temporal as it is backed by a company that is focused on the external community. I'm obviously biased as I started the Cadence project and now leading the temporal project as well as the company. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157400/temporal-workflow-vs-cadence-workflow/61281435#61281435 for more about this topic.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim Fateev, can we do re-try from the cadence or temporal fronted also ? for failed workflows ?

Comment: You can. But you want to code your workflows in a way that they don't fail due to intermittent errors.